# How to run packer provisioner shell script as 'root'

Tags: sudo, packer

I have a packer script with some provisioners, one of which downloads and unzip a file:

```
{
      type: "shell",
      inline: [
        "whoami",
        "ls -la /opt",
        "cd /opt",
        "unzip /tmp/artifactory-oss.zip",
        "mv artifactory-oss-" + version + " artifactory-oss",
        "rm -r /tmp/artifactory-oss.zip",
      ],
    },
```

The error message i get is:

```
19:50:53  ==> docker: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell042070015
19:50:54      docker: jenkins
19:50:54      docker: total 168956
19:50:54      docker: drwxrwxrwt 1 root    root           55 Jan 11 18:50 .
19:50:54      docker: drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root           49 Jan 11 18:50 ..
19:50:54      docker: -rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 173003119 May 21  2021 artifactory-oss.zip
19:50:54      docker: -rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins       145 Jan 11 18:50 script_6912.sh
19:50:54      docker: checkdir error:  cannot create artifactory-oss-6.17.4
19:50:54      docker: Archive:  /tmp/artifactory-oss.zip
19:50:54      docker:                  Permission denied
19:50:54      docker:                  unable to process artifactory-oss-6.17.4/.
```

So the provisioner is run as 'Jenkins' user, but because the `/tmp/` directory is owned by `root` the `jenkins` user is not allowed to unzip and create the `artifactory-oss-6.17.4` directory under `\tmp\`.
I have tried to run it as `root` with `sudo` command, but i get:

```
18:52:22  ==> docker: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell929896218
18:52:23      docker: jenkins
18:52:23      docker: total 0
18:52:23      docker: drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18 Oct 21 16:22 .
18:52:23      docker: /tmp/script_1743.sh: 5: sudo: not found
18:52:23      docker: drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49 Jan 11 17:52 ..
18:52:23      docker: drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21 Jan  4 16:23 java
18:52:23  ==> docker: Killing the container: 75d89e430751d53c67909fe658e8edf264f8a020337d76ec511713f2a1b53843
18:52:23  Build 'docker' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 127
```

The sudo command is not found and unfortunately i cannot install it in this image as it is provided by a third party .
Is there another way i can run it as `root`?

I also add the Jenkinsfile snippet that runs the task:

```
def buildDockerImage = {
  stage('docker') {
    ob.cleanNode('docker') {
      deleteDir()
      unstash name: 'sources'
      dir('working/dir') {
        ob.buildPacker(path: "packer/packer.jsonnet")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the home directory of the Jenkins user instead of `/tmp/`?

Comment: The relevant snippet of your Jenkins Pipeline code would also be helpful here. This would especially include your `agent` directive for the `stage`.

Comment: Thanks @Paolo but at the end i still need to move the unzipped artifact into '/opt' and at that point i get: `mv: cannot move 'artifactory-oss-6.17.4' to '/opt/artifactory-oss': Permission denied`

Comment: @MattSchuchard added

Comment: So this stage is with the default `agent`?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I fixed it by creating a new jenkins agent which runs as 'root'